# Search and offline availability through powershell for all sites

Tags: 2013, powershell, site-settings

If you go to "Site Settings" of any site you will see option "Search and offline availability". Clicking on which will open a page where you can chose one of the following option for "Index ASPX Page Content"

- Do not index Web Parts if this site contains fine-grained permissions
- Always index all Web Parts on this site
- Never index any Web Parts on this site

By default first value is checked.

Is it possible to change this value to "Always index all Web Parts on this site" through powershell for all sites because I have more than 500 sub sites?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try the below code and tweak it as per your requirement.

```
$site=Get-SPSite "http://servername:1111/"
$web=$site.RootWeb;
$web.AllowAutomaticASPXPageIndexing=$true
$web.ASPXPageIndexMode=[Microsoft.SharePoint.WebASPXPageIndexMode]::Never
$web.NoCrawl=$false
$web.Update()
```

[More detail at this site](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anavijai/search-and-offline-availability-in-sharepoint-2010/)